# Unmarshal numbered XML tags in Go

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I've tried quite a lot of structs to try and unmarshal this XML, but I couldn't really figure it out:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type SettingContainer struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name  `xml:"Settings"`
    Settings []Setting `xml:",any"`
}

type Setting struct {
    XMLName          xml.Name          `xml:",any"`
    SettingRegisters []SettingRegister `xml:",any"`
}

type SettingRegister struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:",any"`
    Value   string   `xml:"value,attr"`
}

func main() {
    var xmlData = bytes.NewBufferString(`
    <Settings>
        <Setting0>
            <Setting0_register value="0x20" />
            <Setting0ArbitraryName value="0x0" />
        </Setting0>
        <Setting1>
            <Setting1_register value="0x60" />
            <Setting1WhateverEnable value="0x0" />
        </Setting1>
        <Setting2>
            <Setting2_register value="0x80" />
            <Setting2blahblah value="0x1" />
        </Setting2>
        <Setting4>
            <Setting4_register value="0x2fffff8" />
            <Setting4ThisCanBeAnything value="0x0" />
        </Setting4>
    </Settings>`)

    var s []SettingContainer
    xml.Unmarshal(xmlData.Bytes(), &s)

    for _, i := range s {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

I just can't get it to print anything. The fields I actually need are the value attr of the SettingN_register as well as the SettingN tag names. How can I make it so the xml is unmarshalled into these fields properly? I was looking into making a custom unmarshal function, but I couldn't really find how to make one properly. All I was able to get from this XML was the "Settings" tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `xml:",any"` tags from the `XMLName` fields (this is causing the decoder to try to map the extra child elements to this field), and unmarshal into a `SettingContainer` instead of `[]SettingContainer` as an XML document can only have one root element. Working example here: https://go.dev/play/p/dItnmEGH8oM

```
type SettingContainer struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name  `xml:"Settings"`
    Settings []Setting `xml:",any"`
}

type Setting struct {
    XMLName          xml.Name
    SettingRegisters []SettingRegister `xml:",any"`
}

type SettingRegister struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Value   string `xml:"value,attr"`
}

func main() {
    var xmlData = bytes.NewBufferString(`...`)

    var s SettingContainer
    xml.Unmarshal(xmlData.Bytes(), &s)

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```